# Scrollview wont scroll

Tags: java, android

I have try, I don't know why my Scroll View not working.
I already change child layout of Scroll View to wrap_content height but still not working. my button is in the bottom as I expected but the content should scroll able, and i have toggle content in 1 card view thanks

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <cardview>
        <cardview>
        <cardview>
        <cardview> here i have toggle content

         <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/len_16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/len_12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/len_16dp"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/inverted_corners"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                    <com.prismalink.mbddlibrary.util.UnscrollableList
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:clickable="false"/>

          </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBayar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is work well, sorry for my little fault. just add this to scrollView child and 
i realized that the content is same height with the parent

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/len_64dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `ScrollView` as the root of the `layout`.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
     .......
     .....
```